# ESLint (Airbnb) + Prettier setup for React Native (Expo) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, eslint, prettier

I have been working on setting up linting & formatting for my React Native project for a couple of weeks now, but I'm unable to make much progress. I have looked at many tutorials and followed them as much as I could, but there still seems to be some setup problems.

My project has a Django backend and React Native frontend, therefore the React app (in `src/frontend` directory) started using the tutorial here using Expo, Yarn and TypeScript: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

No further changes were made to this setup, and I attempted to add ESLint & Prettier to it.

These are my configuration files:

1. `.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'import',
    'react',
    'react-hooks',
    'react-native',
    'prettier',
  ],
  extends: [
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-use-before-define': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': ['error'],
    'prettier/prettier': 'error',
  },
};
```

2. `.prettierrc.json`

```json
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

3. `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {}
}
```

To name a few significant errors I am getting, I get `import/namespace` for `react-native` where it says `';' expected`, variable used before definition such as `styles`, and parsing error "parserOptions.project" has been set for `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `.eslintrc.js` does not match the project config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating `tsconfig.eslint.json` with this content:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [".eslintrc.js", "**/*.js", "**/*.jsx", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

and so changing `parserOptions.project` to `'tsconfig.eslint.json'` worked.